# What exact permissions are needed to read and write to Google Sheets for a service account?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I am setting up a node script to interact with a google sheet, all the tutorials I have come across set up a service account with the **Editor** role, however I only want my service account to read and write to a google sheet so I don't want it to have all the permissions an editor role affords. Does anyone know the specific permissions needed for reading and writing to google sheets?

Comment: What are the permission that you don't want or be protected against?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067825/how-to-access-google-spreadsheets-with-a-service-account-credentials

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I don't want any of the excess that the general 'Editor' role provides. This is a quote from GCP on the permissions of the Editor role: "View, create, update, and delete most Google Cloud resources. See the list of included permissions." It has a lot of permissions but I only want those needed to reed and write on a google sheet.

Comment: Ahhhh. No, the editor role in Cloud IAM, but editor in the sharing option on Google Sheet!

Comment: for noobs like me: you have to share the sheet to the service account, to the xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com address you can see on IAM / Permissions tab in the google project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

Editor permission grants read and write access, which also allows the file to be deleted.

Commenter access grands only read access.

You have to choose between the two

Comment: ah, that's depressing but thank you!

Comment: you also may need to explicitly share the sheet with the service account depending on your GCP/Workspace configuration